# I am declaring the button,on buttom i am declaring image,the button clicking is not working

Tags: android, button, imageview

//I am declaring the button,on buttom i am declaring image,when i dragging the image down,the button clicking is not working,button  is not coming forground.how can i declare both button and image in sameplace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Button" />

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/alTop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/dd" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use AbsoluteLayout...It is deprecated.........no means to use that

Comment: yeah i remove  the absolute layout but no use

Answer (score 0):

Try This it might be helpful...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/dd"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: but i want declare android:marigintop = 0dip for button ,and android:marigintop = 0dip for image also.